# File in the network not updating in vb6

Tags: vb6, file-permissions, file-writing

I built software which can run from the network system. If the software which is on the network is run then the software will run as portable app.

When i run the remote application the software will write the log in the remote system itself. There is no error found when writing the log and accessing the log, but the problem is when the log file opened with the any text editors the written data from the application will not be seen in the file but as i said before data can be accessed from coding.

In the coding simple file write method is used to write the stream of data. The strange thing is if i give the permission to EVERYONE for the log file then the problem will be solved and the log file will be updated when opened the log file in the text editors.

Now my question is if the file did not have the permission then why there was no error in the application when writing? Why i am able to access the written data from coding and why not in text editors?

System OS: Windows 10

Text editor used: Notepad, Notepad++, wordpad

**Update:**

Code used to write the log is

```
Open "test.LOG" For Random Access Read Write Lock Write As #i Len = 500
Put #i, record, logstring
```

Comment: Please provide code to accompany your question. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the full file path you are using in the Open?  And are you closing the file before trying to open it from Notepad?

Comment: log file is given relative path with respect of exe. Yes, the file is closed after the writing process before opening the file.